# Magical Record: crash when fetching data in background thread

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a random crash when i perform `MR_findFirstWithPredicate` in a background (not main) thread. I am using `NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()` for all magical record operations on both main and background threads - i think this is the root of the problem, but i am not sure how to fix it.

Should i use some other context when i perform operations in background threads? I tried using `NSManagedObjectContext.MR_context` but all fetches returned nil. Also tried `NSManagedObjectContext.MR_newPrivateQueueContext` but app crashed on each fetch operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, you should be using a context that is NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType to do background. Sounds like the MR_newPrivateQueueContext is the correct call, but you probably you will have to give it a persistent Store or a parentContext. In this case you could set the MR_newPrivateQueueContext parentContext to the defaultContext

```
let defaultContext = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()
let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_newPrivateQueueContext
privateContext.parentContext = defaultContext
```

Comment: Add also, don't forget to use `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` for operations on the `MR_newPrivateQueueContext` you created.